# R cannot recognise the importing files

Tags: r, csv, importdata

I am trying to import a dataset in Rstudio by choosing "Import Dataset" then "From Text(readr)..." and then "Browse.." I choose a csv file. The message that follows is : "Is this a valid CSV file?" In addition, there seems to be another message at the console: "cannot open file 'diet.csv':No such file or directory." This happens with every dataset. I checked out if the working directory is the right, I restarted R, and I deleted Rstudio and installed it again. Is there an idea how can I tackle this problem?

Comment: What happens if you instead run this from the console? `readr::read_csv("C:/your/path/here/diet.csv")` (if you use Windows)

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I write this line the output is "could not find function "read_csv"." I  installed the package readr prior to writting this.

Comment: Odd. I wonder if the installation worked properly - is the output of `"readr" %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"]` TRUE or FALSE?